# I can´t make the query in php5

Tags: php, mysql

I don´t Know why my query is failing.
Here is the code:

```
<?php 

include_once 'conectar.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    echo "ref = ".$ref;

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO `imovelApagado` (
            SELECT * FROM `imovel` 
            WHERE idImovel='$ref'
        )
    ";

    $Qquery = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_query($Qquery) or die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');

    $query1  = "DELETE FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='$ref'"; 
    $Qquery1 = mysql_query($query1);
    mysql_query($Qquery1) or die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');
}

?>
```

It prints this:
ref=2015You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. They're deprecated. Consider using mysqli_* functions, or PDO.

Comment: Also look into SQL injection. Your code is currently very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should check column of imovelApagado and imovel should be matched when u try select *.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

```
<?php 

  include_once 'conectar.php';

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $ref=$_POST['ref'];
    echo "ref=".$ref;

    $query="INSERT INTO `imovelApagado` (SELECT * FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='$ref')";
    if ($Qquery=mysql_query($query)) {
     die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');
    }

    $query1="DELETE FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='$ref'"; 
    if ($Qquery1=mysql_query($query1)) {
      die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you should have two diferent messages in die so you know witch query is failling .

Also check if you have identity on in imovelApagado and make sure taht from youre select youre not trying to insert the same identiy twice.

Also post your structure of the tables if possible. Check if tables structures are identical in the two tables.

**UPDATE** 
please use folowing code

```
include_once 'conectar.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $ref=$_POST['ref'];
                echo "ref=".$ref;

                $query="INSERT INTO `imovelApagado` (SELECT * FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='$ref')";
                mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');

                $query1="DELETE FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='$ref'"; 
                mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error().'<BR><BR>ERRO - NÃO FOI POSSIVEL ENVIAR OS DADOS');
}
```

the problem was that you interogated two times youre querys and the second time you intergoted the mysql response that was true = 1

Comment: the second table is a copy of the first one. I had already tested the two queries seperated and error is the same, I can see information from the tables  but I can´t INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

Answer (score -2):

The first problem I can see in your queries are this:

you need use "{$variable}" for variables into string in php

```
"DELETE FROM `imovel` WHERE idImovel='{$ref}'";
```

But for more information is better if you can show us the query; after assign variable $query or $query1 put:

```
echo $query
```

then we can help you with about the syntax error.

Comment: thanks, the problem was not the query but a relationship between tables